# Remove all white spaces inside specific delimiters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to process a xml file containing wrongly formed elements.

A wrongly formed elemement is one which doesn't respect the following pattern : `<name attribute1=value1 attribute2=value2 ... attributeN=valueN>`

There can be 0 to n attributes.

As a consequence, `<my element number>` is invalid, while `<my element=number>` is not.

Here is a sample of my text :

```
<product_name>
    A high wind in Jamaica <The innocent voyage>  The modern library of the world s best books   Books  Richard Arthur Warren Hughes
</product_name>
```

Here, `<product_name>` is a good element, while `<The innocent voyage>` is not.

When an incorrect element is spotted, I would like to have the `<>` replaced with neutral characters, such as `+`.

Since the file containing these tags is pretty big (1.5 GB), I would rather not use a brute force approach.

Would you guys see an fast (and if possible, elegant) way to solve this problem ?

Comment: open the file into python. `file_string.replace("<", "+").replace(">", "+")`

Comment: This approach will destroy the `xml` structure, wich I want to keep. I just want to remove invalid tags.

Comment: How are you specifying which tags are invalid and which aren't?

Comment: Also note it will load the entire file into memory.

Comment: @sshashank124
To my mind, a correct xml tag is formed like this : `<tag property1=value1 ... propertyn=valueN>`


@C.B. I read this file by block, so memory isn't my concern.

Comment: And an incorrect tag looks like ... ? Can you include both these in your question. Better to have them in one place

Comment: @sshashank124 I just edited, is this more understandable ?

Comment: Yes it is much better now. I believe you are looking for the word `regex`: a python module

Comment: Nope, you need to provide a sample of the text including the good and the bad,

Comment: @sshashank124 I feared so. However, I'm affraid that my regex mastery is is not high enough to tackle this problem alone.

Answer (score 0):

As you state that you would rather stay away from `regex`, I was able to create the following code that doesn't use `regex` (although I'm sure `regex` would be quite useful)

```
def valid_tag(tag):
    temp = tag.split()
    for word in temp[1:]:
        if "=" not in word:
            return False
    return True
```

Here you pass in a tag as a string as the parameter. For example: `"<hello test=test>"`

You can run this test on each tag by creating another method for getting a tag by finding a `"<"` and then the first `">"` that follows and creating a substring from that which will be the tag that you pass into this method.

NOTE: This assumes that your tags are written as follows: `<hello test=test>` and not `< hello test = test >`

This method is still very primitive and makes a few assumptions as I stated above but hopefully it will give you the start you need.

Comment: Yes. My program returns `True` for that

Comment: Oh, right. I always forget `[1:]` takes the second word onwards.